# Resize preview image based on original image output percentage

Tags: javascript, algorithm, image-processing, resize-image

I need some help with a resizing algorithm.

**Scenario:**

- There is an original print-ready image
- There is a preview of this origiginal image to show in the browser. (Let's say with a width of 750px)

From an external system I receive cropping data about the original image. Now I have to display the same cropping-frame on the preview image.

The preview image is placed into an HTML img-tag. The jquery guillotine plugin will be attached to the element to display the image in a "cropping-frame". (https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine)

I managed to calculate the right width, height, x, y, ...
The problem is about setting the right scale for the preview image.

These are the parameters that are returned from the external system:

- Resize percentage of the original image ( = outputPct)
- Ratio of how much the preview image has resized (previewWidth / originalWidth = previewRatio)
  (- width, height, x, y, .... )

**Problem:**

How to calculate the scale for the preview image based on the paramters above?
It is not possible to just use the outputPct because:

- If the original outputPct > 1, then the preview needs to be zoomed in procently more
- If the original outputPct = 1, then the preview needs to be zoomed at 100%
- If the original outputPct < 1, then the preview needs to be zoomed in procently less

The output of the preview needs to be exactly the same as the output of the real image.

Allready tried multiple variations, but haven't managed to find a proper solution.
Propably need to implement a more mathematical solution to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: make a fiddle this is too confusing.

Comment: It's hard to create an example fiddle because the data is pulled from an external system. So most of the code would be more confusing then helpful. I updated the original question to make it a bit less confusing.

Comment: Is the outputPct is the compression ratio. I mean is the outputPct means that outputPct*100 is percentage of compression?

Comment: The outputPct is the amount of procent that the original (print-ready) image is scaled before cropping.
So if it's 50% (=0.5) the original image is scaled half of the original size.
This means that the preview image needs to be scale less then half (>50%) to end up with the correct scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help! After searching for days, I found out that it wasn't a wrong outputPct. The problem was the DPI. Previews are always generated at 96dpi and originals can be any dpi.
When calculating the scale I needed to make sure that I multiplied the outputPct with the dpiRatio.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, there’s an image (the **original**) that’s being cropped to which you don’t have access or can’t use, and there’s a **preview** of that image you can work with. You need to generate the **exact same cropped image** that an external system generates out of the original, but **using the preview** image instead.

The easier way to explain it is that basically you should **convert the preview into the original** image again so that you can apply the same transformations than the external system and get the exact same output. You have the **ratio** between the preview and the original image (`previewWidth/originalWidth`), by multiplying the dimensions of the preview by the inverse of the ratio you’d get the original image.

If that’s clear we can make it all at once. Instead of scaling the preview up and then applying the cropping scale (I guess *outputPct*), directly apply a scale of `(1/ratio)*croppingScale` and keep the rest just as the external system gives it to you. Using [Guillotine](//github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine#api) it would be:

```
var ratio = previewWidth / originalWidth; # = previewHeight / originalHeight

$('#preview-img').guillotine({
  width:  croppingWidth,  # The width of the original image after it's cropped!
  height: croppingHeight, 
  init: {
    x: xOffset,   # Movements over the x and y axes (if any) 
    y: yOffset,   # just as given by the external system.
    scale: croppingScale / ratio
  }
});
```

That should get you the same output, but keep in mind that even though it will have the same dimensions and contain the same section of the image if the preview is significantly smaller you’ll get a noticeable loss in image quality.

I hope that solves it, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is indeed what I was also trying, but didn't get working. The solution was to multiply the outputPct with a DPI-ratio. For the Width, Height, X & Y I needed to use the preview/original ratio.